# Android : Animate Rating Bar

Tags: android, android-animation, ratingbar

I'm creating an android app which needs rating bar to denote the progress of each level.
I've figured how to use rating bars both custom and default now i would like to add animation to the rating bar progress.

Whenever I set the number of stars (mean I've set `android:isIndicator="true"` using only for displaying to user not editable by him) it should do some animation like rotate and fill the bar.Please help me out with the code fragment  I should use.

I've included code that i used for rating bar creation:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    style="@style/myRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3"
    android:isIndicator="true" />
```

drawable/ratingstars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="myRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">22dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">22dip</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

please help me to add animation to rating when i use setRating(int) from activity

Comment: Have you tried reading the Android [Animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To animate the rating to a particular value, you can use a [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) (API 11+).

Here's an example of animating a RatingBar from its current value to 5:

```
RatingBar myRatingBar = findViewById(R.id.my_rating_bar);
float current = myRatingBar.getRating();

ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myRatingBar, "rating", current, 5f);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

For more information on how to animate properties of a View, read the [Property Animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

I'm not sure what you are looking for in a rotate animation, but this should give you a good starting point for adding in the animations you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Though i thought of a diff animation the thing which you provided was satisfactory. As a beginner i find this useful. Yet i wonder how rating animations like those in angry birds game are being done...

Comment: Many games use OpenGL or game engines such as Unity to draw on a Canvas instead of using Views.